# Mock HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking, nunit

I have written a test class for my controller class using NUnit and Moq framework.My classes are following

```
public class ClientTypeControllerTest 
{
private Mock<IClientTypeService> _clientTypeServiceMock;
private Mock<IClientTypeAudService> _clientTypeAudServiceMock;
private Mock<IClientTypeHisService> _clientTypeHisServiceMock;
private Mock<HttpSessionStateBase> _sessionMock;
private Mock<HttpResponseBase> _httpresponceMock;
private Mock<IUserAccountService> _userAccountService;

ClientTypeController objClientTypeController;
protected Users LoggedInUser { get; set; }
List<ClientTypeAud> lists;


[SetUp]
public void Initialize()
{
    //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
    _clientTypeServiceMock = new Mock<IClientTypeService>();
    _clientTypeAudServiceMock = new Mock<IClientTypeAudService>();
    _clientTypeHisServiceMock = new Mock<IClientTypeHisService>();
    _userAccountService = new Mock<IUserAccountService>();
    _sessionMock = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
    _httpresponceMock = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
    var ctrlContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();

    AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
    _sessionMock.SetupGet(s => s["LOGGED_IN_USER"]).Returns(users);
    ctrlContext.Setup(p => p.HttpContext.Session).Returns(_sessionMock.Object);

}



[Test]
public void Show_AllClientTypeRecords_InGridView_UnitTest()
{
     lists = new List<ClientTypeAud>()  {
     new ClientTypeAud() { Id = 1, CTypeName = "INR", CompanyId = 1, Active = "Y" },
     new ClientTypeAud() { Id = 1, CTypeName = "ABC", CompanyId = 1, Active = "Y" },
     new ClientTypeAud() { Id = 1, CTypeName = "AVM", CompanyId = 1, Active = "Y" }
   };

    _clientTypeAudServiceMock.Setup(x => x.All()).Returns(lists.AsQueryable());
    objClientTypeController = new ClientTypeController(_clientTypeServiceMock.Object, 
                  _clientTypeAudServiceMock.Object, _clientTypeHisServiceMock.Object, 
                                                       _userAccountService.Object);

var result = objClientTypeController.GridData("", "asc", 1, 1) as JsonResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(result.Data);
 }
}
```

And my BaseController class is ,

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
public SessionProvider SessionProvider;
protected Users LoggedInUser { get; set; }

public string actionName { get; set; }        
protected string controllerName { get; set; }
protected string area { get; set; }

public BaseController()
{
    actionName = 
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    controllerName = 
      System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.
                                                GetRequiredString("controller");
    SessionProvider = new SessionProvider(Session);
    LoginMethod();            
    ViewBag.Menu = BuildMenu();

}
 ......
  ......
```

When I run my test class using NUnit then it shows Nullreferenceexception was unhandled by user code on

```
  actionName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.
                             RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
```

This is in my BaseControllerClass. So I don't know how to Moq the data for HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.so please Can anybody please help to find the solution

Comment: Why do you need action and controller name in base controller? If you need it anyway, have you looked at [mvccontrib.testhelpers](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper)? They have ways to mock `HTTPCnntext`.

Comment: This is not ASP.Net MVC code (should be using `HttpContextBase`)- are you sure you tagged properly?

Comment: Yes, this is MVC4 Razor.And i followed the  mvccontrib.testhelpers but did not work. I tried it in a lot of ways but I can't find the solution, So please if you can help then help me.

Comment: You should be making use of the HttpContextBase class and inject that into your controller.

Comment: Can you give some example code please?

Answer (score 4):

Before you setup your RouteData, you need to fake your HttpContext. The simplest way is

```
HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(
    new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost/", ""), 
    new HttpResponse(new StringWriter()));
```

So now you can compose your RequestContext to meet your requirement. Mock a HttpContext first, and create your RouteData instance.

```
var contextBase = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var routeData = new RouteData();
routeData.Values["controller"] = "anyControllerNameYouWant";
routeData.Values["action"] = "anyActionNameYouWant";
```

The last, just assign these to your fake HttpContext.Current and done.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext = new 
    RequestContext(contextBase.Object, routeData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a wrapper for the HttpContext operations and mock the wrapper calls (by using an interface) in the UT with a framework like Rhino Mocks.

You will create an interface IHttpContextWrapper with one method "string GetRequiredStringFromRequestRouteData (string valueName)".

After that you should create an implementation of the interface. Say "public class HttpContextWrapper : IHttpContextWrapper" and you will use the HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredData(valueName) inside the implementation of GetRequiredStringFromRequestRouteData.

In you client class you can inject with dependency injection (by using Spring.NET framework or Unity) the implementation to be used either by property or be constructor.

However, when you will test the client in you Unit Test you will inject a mock object that is created based on the interface and you will mock the call "GetRequiredStringFromRequestRouteData" to return whatever you want. You can do that by using a Mocking framework like Rhino Mocks.

Comment: Can you give some example code for it?  Please help me

Comment: I tried what you have said above, but NotSupportedException is occurring. And till now I didn't find any solution, anybody please help

Comment: Please give us your new implementation to review it.

Comment: Created an interface IHttpContextWrapper with one method "string GetRequiredStringFromRequestRouteData (string valueName)".And then Implemented it to "public class HttpContextWrapper".And in my test class , var url = objClientTypeController.Url.Action("ManageClientType", "ClientType");            httpContextWrapper.GetRequiredStringFromRequestRouteData(url);

Comment: And also, did like this "_httpContextWrapper.Setup(x => x.GetRequiredStringFromRequestRouteData("AddEditClientType")).Returns("AddEditClientType");" Now it shows NotSupportedException

Comment: You are not using the mocking expectation call correctly.

Comment: You should use Expect.Call schema.

Comment: Can you give some example code please? Because I am not familiar with unit test.

Answer (score 1):

You should add Fakes Assembly for System.Web.dll

In Solution Explorer, expand your unit test project’s References.

1. If you are working in Visual Basic, you must select Show All Files in the Solution Explorer toolbar, in order to see the References list.
2. Select the assembly that contains the classes definitions for which you want to create shims. For example, if you want to shim HttpContext, select System.Web.dll
3. On the shortcut menu, choose Add Fakes Assembly.

Then create a shimcontext and within that context mock / detour the execution of desired method.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestCurrentYear()
{
    using(ShimContext.Create()) 
    {
        // Arrange:
        System.Web.Fakes.ShimHttpContext....
    }
}
```

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176.aspx,

OR

You can try a different approach using an AspNet Simulator created especially for unit testing at the  Controller level of an Mvc Application. An examples can be found here:
https://github.com/ibrahimbensalah/Xania.AspNet.Simulator/tree/master/Xania.AspNet.Simulator.Tests